# CORS error in angularjs + PHP application

Tags: php, angularjs, cors

I'm working on AngularJS and PHP application. When I try to run the index.html page, its throwing this error,

> MLHttpRequest cannot load http://...... No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
>   The response had HTTP status code 500.

Working on LAMP.
I know I need to include the header files. But where should I include it? Should I include it in config.php where I had definded my database? If not then where??

Comment: You can allow the cross origin request in your php code. So the error won't come again

Comment: how? @SulthanAllaudeen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing CORS settings on your PHP `headers`, try adding following:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Request-With');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
```

Comment: Worked Thanks. @daan.desmedt

Comment: Great to hear! :)

Answer (score 1):

Set header:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com', false);
```

Comment: does example.com need to replace with the localhost or our domain name?

Comment: Domain name that you want to allow