# 500 internal error in angular 4 on using Code igniter REST

Tags: angular, codeigniter, angular-cli

When i submit the form in Angular 4 , form data is printing in console but it is showing following error:

> `OPTIONS http://localhost/gemService/api/registerUser 500 (Internal Server Error)`

For server side i'm using Codeigniter REST API with JSON

Please check this [console log error stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwxzD.png) screenshot

Comment: Enable CORS at the server end.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is due to a `CROSS-ORIGIN` situation. It is prompted when your requests doesn't have the correct headers or your server side doesn't support them. (In `localhost` it can happen when you are requesting a service for example in port 80 and then you ask for something else async in port 8080 or else and you don't have the correct headers).

In your PHP headers you can put

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Request-With');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
```

Also see [CORS error in angularjs + PHP application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42133159/cors-error-in-angularjs-php-application)

Comment: you're welcome, it would be very helpful if you mark the answer as correct (using the check mark at the left of my answer. Regards

Comment: Hi Thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it is a CORS error. You should configure code igniter to allow requests from localhost. 
Here is a web site that explains how : http://www.competa.com/blog/enable-cors-origin-resource-sharing-on-codeigniter-rest-server/